# Dealing with XMLType columns in Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, xmltype

I have a table with an `XMLType` column with content like this:

```xml
<root>
 <item>
  <case>1234</case>
  <open>1</open>
 </item>
 <item>
  <case>2345</case>
  <open>0</open>
 </item>
 <item>
  <case>3456</case>
  <open>1</open>
 </item>
 /* ..other item blocks may follow.. */
</root>
```

**I would like to check if there are open/closed cases.
 What should I put in the query WHERE clause?**

Currently, I got it working in the worst way possible:

```sql
SELECT somecolumn FROM sometable 
WHERE INSTR(EXTRACT(myxmlcolumn, '//open/text()'), '1') > 0
```

Basically, I'm "flattening" all open elements' values to a string (in the sample xml above: `101`) and then find out if there are occurrences of `0` close or `1` open. I need something better which can be indexed to avoid a full table scan.

**Is there any way to retrieve with a SQL query the "case" elements which have the corresponding "open" value set to `1` or `0`?**

I'm currently doing this from my application code parsing the whole XML since I've not been able to find any documentation on how to do it from Oracle side.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by XPATH:

```
select myxmlcolumn.EXTRACT('//item[open=0]/case') from sometable
```

if you want both, open = 1 OR =0 then

```
select myxmlcolumn.EXTRACT('//item[open=0 | open=1]/case') from sometable
```

Comment: That worked like a charm, but I had modify the query to:
`select EXTRACT(myxmlcolumn, '//item[open=1]/case') from sometable`. 
I've also been able to create an index on it, but needed to put `.getStringVal()` at the end of the EXTRACT function to get it work. Thanks a lot.